# how Hazelcast evict the entry from IMap

Tags: java, hazelcast

Quick question about the hazelcast eviction of entry..

I have a IMap with a size (**map_size_per_jvm**) is 6 which is backed by MapStore (saved into mysql database) and write-delay-seconds set at 60 sec.

If I get data (within 10 sec interval) map size 6 at 60 sec what will happen?
***Will it store data first or evict data first?
If it evicts data first, how would i store data first before eviction kicks off?***
Please don't say by setting **eviction-delay-seconds**: I am able to delay.

Should I use **EntryListener** (when evict event fires am I able to store it into a database)?

Answer (score 1):

Before eviction, hazelcast persists data whatever its write-delay-second is. You can easily check this calling evict() manually.